# Where shall I put new/delete when creating a class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a portion of code that I tested and works, and now I would like to make it a class in order to have something cleaner.
The following code creates a scene containing a rectangle and displays it on the widget 'graphicview'

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
QGraphicsRectItem *rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
rect->setRect(0,0,100,100);
scene->addItem(rect);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

What I would like now is to create a class that contains this scene, so that I just have to call :

```
MyClass *myscene = new MyClass;
ui->graphicsView->setScene(myscene->scene)
```

The quetion is, in the class MyClass, shall I have a private argument declared as `QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;`, or just a private argument `QGraphicsScene *scene` and then within the constructor `*scene=new QGraphicsScene`

And the same for where I should put the delete, within the destructor of MyScene?

edit : Based on answer, I tried to rework my code without `new`:

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsRectItem rect;
rect.setRect(0,0,100,100);
scene.addItem(&rect);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(&scene);
```

But this code doesn't work (widget 'graphicView' displays nothing), and all the example I found of Qt use the new operator. What I am missing ?

Comment: You shouldn't put `new`s or `delete`s anywhere. Instead, you should open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use smart pointers, and use them instead.

Comment: What's wrong with just `MyClass myscene;`?

Comment: Well I don't know if anything is wrong, but [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) use them and I'm not at the point where I think they are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid (Raw) pointers as much as your performance and clarity considerations allow. For example, In your code, It's not necessary to use pointers. Instead, define your scene as a member of your class:

```
class MyCalss
{
...
  QGraphicsScene scene;
};
```

And then set it for a view:

```
MyClass myscene;

ui->graphicsView->setScene(&myscene.scene);
```

So, from now on, before using pointers, ask this question from yourself, **Is it necessary to use pointers?** If you have to use pointers, put [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) in your considerations too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I based my exemple on this [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) ('MainWindow Class Implementation'), shall I conclude that Qt does not use good programing practices and I shouldn't use their examples?

Comment: Qt is para-C++, they need a meta-compiler to exist (MOC). Any object derived from QObject form a tree so that you don't need to `delete`. That was clever and powerfull when it was invented, since old C++ hadn't better options. But now, it sounds archaic compared to Modern C++. But Qt is still quite OK.

Comment: @sayanel Qt's examples are great. But you'd better improve your C++ knowledge. Learn from examples what they want to create, not HOW. Secondly, it's better to accept an answer, if it answered your question. [It's good stackoverflow practice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :D ;)

Comment: @s4eed well I tried to implement your answer, but I didn't manage to (see my edit on the question), so it is not closed for now

Comment: @sayanel I guess that you defined your edited code inside your constructor. So after finishing your constructor, your scene will be destroyed. Define your scene 
 a member of the class. The scene has to be alive as long as your view is alive. So you have to `new` and delete it in destructor, or make it a member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "specific" place to put new and delete. It entirely depends on where you need a dynamic allocation of memory (new) and once the job od dynamically allocated memory(the variable) is over you need to free that (delete) keeping in mind that the variable won't be used anywhere else as it would lead to undesired behavior.

If at every object creation of a class, the class variable needs to be dynamically allocated right from starting, do it in constructor. Similarily if the variable is used throughout object lifetime delete it in destructor. This is just a very high level idea. I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695393/c-and-when-to-use-delete/26695418) and also reading more about pointers (smart pointers) and dynamic memory allocation

Comment: *There is no "specific" place to put new and delete* -> *There is no place to put new and delete* since one should not use `new` or `delete` ;)

Comment: Yeah, as they say in "Modern C++" :p