# g++ gives warning for deleting an array for one code but not the other

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

I come from a Java background and am still confused as to how pointers and stuff work. I have 2 examples.

```
int arr[10] = {};
delete[] arr;
```

Here, my compiler throws a warning about deleting `arr`.

```
int *arr = new int[4];
delete[] arr;
```

But it doesn't throw a warning here? Why is that?

Comment: Each `new` has a corresponding `delete`. No `new` -> no `delete`.

Comment: Because in the second case you are using `delete[]` correctly. Simply put, if you use `new[]` then at some point you need to use `delete[]`. BTW 'throw' has a specific meaning in C++ (to do with exceptions). Compilers don't throw warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code, `arr` is statically allocated (on the stack), and will be automatically freed when going out of scope. Calling `delete[]` on statically allocated variables is pointless.

In your second code, `arr` is dynamically allocated on the heap, and will *not* automatically be freed when going out of scope, hence the need to call `delete[]` on it.

Get more information on the right usage of delete here: [C++ and when to use delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695393/c-and-when-to-use-delete)