# Understanding clang-tidy "DeadStores" and "NewDeleteLeaks" warnings

Tags: c++, clang-format, clang-tidy

I am relatively new to c++ programming, especially when dealing with OOP and pointers.

I am trying to implement a binary search tree, and here is the code I have

```cpp
struct TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;

  TreeNode() : val(0), left(NULL), right(NULL){};
  TreeNode(int v) : val(v), left(NULL), right(NULL){};
  TreeNode(int v, TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r) : val(v), left(l), right(r){};
};

void insert(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* v) {
  // inserts v into root, assuming values distinct
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = v; // L52
    return;
  }
  if (v == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  // traverse through tree using structure of BST
  TreeNode* cur = root;
  while (cur != NULL) {
    if (cur->val <= v->val) {
      if (cur->right == NULL) {
        cur->right = new TreeNode(v->val);
        break;
      }
      cur = cur->right;
    } else if (cur->val >= v->val) {
      if (cur->left == NULL) {
        cur->left = new TreeNode(v->val);
        break;
      }
      cur = cur->left;
    }
  }
}

void insert(TreeNode* root, int v) {
  insert(root, new TreeNode(v)); // L78
}
```

Now, I have *two* questions.

1. I realised that the L52 labelled above would not work. For example, if I do `TreeNode* node = new TreeNode(5); TreeNode* empty = NULL; insert(empty, node);`, it would not work. I am not sure how to fix this, so any help would be great.
2. Running clang-tidy on my code, I get the following slightly confusing warning:

```cpp
./main.cpp:78:69: warning: Potential memory leak [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
void insert(TreeNode* root, int v) { insert(root, new TreeNode(v)); }
                                                                    ^
./main.cpp:132:3: note: Calling 'insert'
  insert(node, 3);
  ^
./main.cpp:78:51: note: Memory is allocated
void insert(TreeNode* root, int v) { insert(root, new TreeNode(v)); }
                                                  ^
./main.cpp:78:69: note: Potential memory leak
void insert(TreeNode* root, int v) { insert(root, new TreeNode(v)); }
                                                                    ^
```

I am not sure what this means, and whether it would be dangerous in any way. I found [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/checkers.html#cplusplus-newdelete) from the LLVM docs and it seems that the temporary `new TreeNode(v)` is causing the problem. What is a better way to achieve what I want? Any further explanation or resources that I can read would be great.

Of course, any improvement to my bad coding style would be great as well ;) formatter saves the day.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code seems to leak like a noodle-sieve. Did you consider calling `delete` for anything you `new`ed?

Comment: So should I create a temporary variable like `TreeNode* tmp = new TreeNode(v)`, then insert it, then `delete` it afterwards?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695393/when-to-use-new-and-delete, or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c

Comment: There is now such thing as "**temporary** new TreeNode(v)". C++ does not have garbage collection, everything you allocate with `new` must be somewhere deallocated with `delete`. *How* is up to you.

Comment: What about the first question? My goal is that when I call `insert(empty, node)`, the empty (first argument) will become `node`, but a simple assignment doesn't work here

Comment: @GarethMa you should keep track of a tree root or such, and pass that instead of a `NULL` value. Make `void insert(TreeNode* & root, int v) {` taking a reference parameter, you can actually change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Q1: How do I insert into a binary tree?

The main problem with the fragment:

```
void insert(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* v) {
  // inserts v into root, assuming values distinct
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = v; // L52
    return;
  }
```

is, although you have set a new value for `root`, `root` is a parameter to the `insert` function, and consequently is discarded when `insert` returns.

One way to fix this is to *return* the new value:

```
TreeNode*             // <-- changed return type
    insert(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* v) {
  // inserts v into root, assuming values distinct
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = v; // L52
    return root;      // <---- changed to return a value
  }
```

Every place `insert` returns (including at the end), return the value of `root`.

Then when you call `insert`, save the returned value:

```
TreeNode* root = ...;       // some existing tree
root = insert(root, 5);     // insert 5 and save the result
```

Now, the new value of `root` points to the tree that contains the inserted value.

### Q2: What is clang-tidy complaining about?

Invoking `new` allocates memory.  It must eventually be freed, otherwise (if this keeps happening) your program will eventually use all available memory.  See the question [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c).  Note especially this advice: "every time you type `new`, type `delete`."

Now, in this code as it stands, the problem is actually *not* the missing `delete`, it is the failure to return the updated `root`.  `clang-tidy` realizes that, because the updated `root` is never returned, you can't possibly eventually `delete` it, so complains.  Once you start returning that value, `clang-tidy` will wait to see what you do next.

As for what to do next, one simple approach is to regard `TreeNode` as *owning* its children, meaning it is obliged to `delete` them when it is destroyed.  For example, first add a *destructor* method to `TreeNode`:

```
struct TreeNode {
  ...
  ~TreeNode() {        // <--- this is the destructor
    delete left;       // free left child (if not NULL)
    delete right;      // free right child
  }
};
```

Then in your code that manipulates trees, remember to `delete` the root node when finished:

```
TreeNode* root = NULL;
root = insert(root, 1);
root = insert(root, 2);
delete root;            // <--- free entire tree
```

### A note about smart pointers

My suggestions above use a very direct, literal style of memory management, with explicit use of `new` and `delete` where needed.  However, it is easy to forget to use `delete`, and tricky to get it right in the presence of exceptions.  A commonly preferred alternative is to use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).  But that's a somewhat advanced topic, so when just starting out, I recommend first getting comfortable with explicit `new` and `delete`, but keep in mind there is a better way when you're ready for it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The reason why I want to do the insertion in-place is because I can then turn it into a method and do something like `root->insert(v)`, I guess similar to using vectors where you just do `vec.push_back(...)` instead of `vec = ...`. I will try out your suggestions ;)

Comment: @GarethMa I see.  In that case, you could create another struct, perhaps called `Tree`, that contains the `TreeNode *root` pointer, and then put your methods on the `Tree` container.