# How to release BYTE memory?

Tags: c++, new-operator, free, securezeromemory

Quick question: do I have to / how do I release memory from this allocation of memory?

`unsigned char *uString = new unsigned char[4096]();`

And if I have to, would I do it like this?

`free(uString); delete[] uString;`

Comment: `new` goes with `delete`, `new[]` goes with `delete[]`. `malloc` goes with `free`.
But since you use C++, you never use `malloc` or `free` (or better, you are advised to not use them)

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: The first result on google suggests a question with a high rated answer and 4 references. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c

Comment: @Raildex Well, there is one use for `malloc` still, and that's implementing containers. Reimplementing `std::vector` would require `malloc`. But the chance that you will need to implement a container from scratch (school assignments rarely require useful implementation) are next to 0.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `malloc()` is not required for creating containers. `new[]` can be used for that.

Comment: Sidenote: When you are given memory by a function that isn't  from the `*alloc` family or `new` consult the documentation for that function on how to release the memory. If you don't know how to release something, find out. Using the wrong method might look like it works right up until the the worst possible moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `free` function when you allocate memory with the C functions like `malloc` `calloc` and more.

In c++ you use the operators `new` and `delete` (Also thier array friends `new[]` and `delete[]`).

When you want to delete object created with the operator `new[]`, you call the operator `delete[]`.
For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    int* a = new int;
    delete[] arr;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

And that's all. That will also call the destructor an all of that.

Comment: So the destructor will also null the memory bytes?

Comment: @JeffR No. `free`,`delete` and `delete[]` are only guaranteed to do the absolute minimum, free the memory up for reuse. It doesn't necessarily mark the storage in any way or return it to the underlying system. Many debuggers will mark freed memory with an easily-identifiable pattern to help you spot bugs and some implementations may attempt to increase security by zeroing memory, but none of this is required because it will slow down programs that do not need this special treatment.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation. Do you see any issue with using this `#define` to free and clear the memory? `#define SAFENEWFREE(x) do { RtlSecureZeroMemory(x, _tcslen(x)); delete[] x; } while (0)`

Comment: @JeffR, I think that if you use C++, you should use only `free` and `delete`. Because they are the safest option to have. If someone wants to have other way to delete memory, he just overrides the `delete` operator. If you use C, then it depends on the code itself.