# How to create a shared pointer with make_shared using the Object pointer passed into Function?

Tags: c++

I create an instance of object and get a pointer to that then pass into a function. The function responsible for capturing that pointer and storing it inside an unordered_map.

I made several attempts to make it compile but none of them works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Foo {
    std::string name;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> zoo;

void bar(Foo *foo) {
    zoo.emplace("zilla", std::move(std::make_shared<Foo>(foo)));
}


int main()
{
    // Normal
    Foo foo;
    foo.name = "Stackoverflow";
    
    // Get Pointer
    Foo *fuzzy = &foo;
    
    bar(fuzzy);

    return 0;
}
```

What should be the correct way to call `make_shared` in this case?

Note that I don't want to create the shared_ptr for the pointer rather the object itself.

Comment: `make_shared` is not for converting some existing pointer that came from some mysterious source into a shared pointer. Shared pointers don't work this way. If you don't know where the pointer came from you can't assume by default that it can be converted into a shared pointer. It can very well be in automatic storage ***like in this case***, and after converting it into a shared pointer hillarity ensues.

Comment: The "make" in "make_shared" is creational - think "make me a pizza", not "make me a millionaire". (I personally think it was a mistake to choose "make" over "create" when naming these functions.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't want to convert pointer to shared_ptr rather the object the pointer points into. Does dereferencing works in this case?

Comment: Why would you think it wouldn't work? Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It compiles. I mean I'm not sure about undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: And why, specifically, are you not sure about that? What are the examples of using `make_shared` in your textbook, and how does your textbook explain what it does; which part of that explanation is unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A lot of times, Stack is enough for me and I don't use pointers most of times. The book had make_shared examples with direct objects without pointers. Understand me, I'm not comfortable enough with Pointers. So, if you say, it's legal then I will take it!

Comment: @jeffbRTC you're going to have an undefined behaviour not because of the `shared_ptr` but because of your `Foo foo`;

Comment: @Moia That's how an Object initialized. What cause an undefined behavior here? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @jeffbRTC `make_shared<type>(arguments)`, creates a new, shareable, object of the type `type` using the constructor of `type` that matches the arguments. What you saw was creating a shareable copy of an object.

Comment: @jeffbRTC that's how an object is statically initialized. When your `foo` object get out of scope, your pointers are garbage and you do have an UB. You -have to- dinamically initialize your `foo` with a `new` and then store the pointer. Using `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` behave exactly the same. I would suggest you to find a book about C++ and learn what the difference between `Foo foo;` and `Foo* foo = new Foo;`

Comment: @Moia Then my suspicion is correct. I will go with the answer on below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "new" and when not to, in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c)

Comment: @Moia Not really, I was avoiding "new" so I don't think this is a duplicate but glad to know it can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: @jeffbRTC avoiding using the keyword `new` and avoid dynamic initialization are completely two different things. You weren't doing the former, you were doing the latter, that's what I'm trying to make you understand. Shared pointer is just a new with scoped managed memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bar` should take `std::shared_ptr`:

```
void bar(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo) {
    zoo.emplace("zilla", std::move(foo));
}

int main()
{
    // Normal
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    foo->name = "Stackoverflow";
    
    bar(foo);
}
```

Comment: There is no "fuzzy" in your code. Should be foo, right?

Comment: @jeffbRTC: typo fixed.

Comment: @jeffbRTC also consider `std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> zoo;` instead of a shared ptr.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili That will work on minimal app but not in real world app.

Comment: @jeffbRTC in the real world, you rarely, if ever, *need* shared_ptr. have a look at `unique_ptr` if you absolutely must use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variant of Jarod's anwser. `shared_ptr` is implicitly convertible from a raw pointer so it's enough to pass the raw pointer to the function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Foo {
    std::string name;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> zoo;

void bar(Foo *foo) {
    zoo.emplace("zilla", foo);
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = new Foo;
    foo->name = "Stackoverflow";
    
    // zoo will take the ownership of foo   
    bar(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the code is not related with `shared_ptr` at all. Since you're not dynamically initializing your object with a `new` (or a `make_shared`) but with

```
Foo foo;
```

When the scope of where foo is initialized ends, foo is destructed and any pointer you're referring to become garbage, and you will have an undefined behaviour.

About dynamic initialization I'd suggest [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c)

Comment: That variant is **dangerous**, as ownership transfer is implicit and not visible.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree with you. I posted it with the sole purpose to show how it works, since he didn't have clear about dynamic memory more than how using a shared_ptr

Comment: Not sure that showing bad (as dangerous) (even if working) code, especially to beginners, as solution is good, even more without warning about the danger/pitfall.