# Why no "delete" after "new" in linked list insert node

Tags: c++, linked-list, new-operator, delete-operator

I have been trying to understand memory allocation in C++ by reading some texts and looking stuff up. I have seen often that one should always call "delete" after "new". However, I also see code like this:

```
void LinkedList::add(int data){
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->data = data;
    node->next = this->head;
    this->head = node;
    this->length++;
}
```

In structures like linked lists or stacks.

I have seen some great explanations on SO like:

[Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)
[When to use "new" and when not to, in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c)

*However I am still confused why one would not call "delete" here for a new Node.*

Edit: Let me clarify my question. I understand why not to immediately call delete in the same method. However, in the same code I do not see a matching delete statement for add. I assume that everything is deleted once the program ends, but I am confused that there is no apparent matching delete statement (ie: count all the news in the code, count all the deletes in the code, they do not match).

Edit: Here is the source that I am looking at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/

The code for their linked list:

```
// A complete working C++ program to demonstrate
//  all insertion methods on Linked List
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
// A linked list node
class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
 
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer)
to the head of a list and an int, inserts
a new node on the front of the list. */
void push(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();
 
    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
 
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
 
    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
 
/* Given a node prev_node, insert a new node after the given
prev_node */
void insertAfter(Node* prev_node, int new_data)
{
    /*1. check if the given prev_node is NULL */
    if (prev_node == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"the given previous node cannot be NULL";
        return;
    }
 
    /* 2. allocate new node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();
 
    /* 3. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
 
    /* 4. Make next of new node as next of prev_node */
    new_node->next = prev_node->next;
 
    /* 5. move the next of prev_node as new_node */
    prev_node->next = new_node;
}
 
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end */
void append(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();
 
    Node *last = *head_ref; /* used in step 5*/
 
    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
 
    /* 3. This new node is going to be
    the last node, so make next of
    it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;
 
    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty,
    then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }
 
    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
 
    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}
 
// This function prints contents of
// linked list starting from head
void printList(Node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<node->data;
        node = node->next;
    }
}
 
/* Driver code*/
int main()
{
    /* Start with the empty list */
    Node* head = NULL;
     
    // Insert 6. So linked list becomes 6->NULL
    append(&head, 6);
     
    // Insert 7 at the beginning.
    // So linked list becomes 7->6->NULL
    push(&head, 7);
     
    // Insert 1 at the beginning.
    // So linked list becomes 1->7->6->NULL
    push(&head, 1);
     
    // Insert 4 at the end. So
    // linked list becomes 1->7->6->4->NULL
    append(&head, 4);
     
    // Insert 8, after 7. So linked
    // list becomes 1->7->8->6->4->NULL
    insertAfter(head->next, 8);
     
    cout<<"Created Linked list is: ";
    printList(head);
     
    return 0;
}
 
 
// This code is contributed by rathbhupendra
```

Comment: see "Reasons to use dynamic allocation" in accepted answer: "You want to allocate memory which will persist after leaving the current block. [...]". The node should be deleted later when it isnt needed anymore, not right after creating it

Comment: You don't immediately call `delete` after `new`, but when the object is no longer used/before it goes out of scope, you call `delete` so the memory is freed, and ensures that your program doesn't eat all the resources of your PC

Comment: What leads you to conclude that destroying the new node is a useful thing to do while adding it to the list?

Comment: "in the same code I do not see a matching delete statement for add" this isnt the complete code. Does the `LinkedList` have a destructor?

Comment: Maybe that code is just particularly badly written.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have appended the source now

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have appended the source now

Comment: This code is actually badly written. It misses `deleteNode`/`deleteList`/`popNode` functionality, so yeah `delete` is not technically called. Probably the best way would be to overload `operator delete` for `LinkedList`

Comment: @Steak: "*Here is the source that I am looking at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org*" Oh, that explains it. You shouldn't take anything on that site seriously.

Comment: The rule is that every object created with `new` should **eventually** be destroyed with a corresponding call to `delete`. The rules doesn't mean that every `new` in a function should be matched with a `delete` in the same function. But really, that rule is a bit out of date. The modern version would be "Don't use `new` to create objects. Use `std::make_unique` instead.".

Comment: @NicolBolas Could you link me a reliable implementation?

Comment: Every time I see something from geeksforgeeks.org I find that it is pretty bad. I would recommend against using it as a source to learn C++.

Comment: @Lala5th Could you link me a reliable implementation?

Comment: @Steak This looks better https://gist.github.com/Amadeeus/1c6dc6f5ea3d7b84bb979f7482b70342, but haven't looked into it in detail

Comment: @Lala5th Great, thank you. So the idea is that they really should have included "delete" somewhere, probably in the deconstructor then?

Comment: when C++ tutorial code starts with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` you should close the tab and move elsewhere. This code isnt portable C++

Comment: @Steak Generally the destructor would be a prime candidate, however depending on use, deleting specific elements could be useful as well. Also as it was pointed out `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a red flag, but `using namespace std;` should be seen cautiouslty as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you cited should `delete` the nodes at some point. Indeed, that code shows off tons of bad C++ practices. It doesn't delete the nodes because it's bad code.

Oh and BTW: ignore anything on the site you linked to. If there is something useful on that site, it's only by accident.

Comment: Great to know. I'll probably bite the bullet and just fully read some book instead.

Comment: By accident indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Generally `new` does a couple of things. It allocates memory for an object, on the heap (where dynamic memory resides), and initialises an object at the address.

When you have variables in your function like this:

```cpp
void example(){
    int a;
    char b;
}
```

They reside on the stack, and when the function returns, those variables no longer exist. With `new` you can get memory outside the stack (on the heap). The good thing is that this persists throughout function calls. The bad thing that it persists across function calls. It's good because sometimes array lengths are not known and therefore they can not be allocated on  the stack, or you need a large buffer which would not fit on the stack. It's bad because if you forget about it, then it won't go away. It will just sit there taking up memory. `delete`, basically destructs the object at the address, and then returns the memory to the OS. That's why people say that `delete` should be called after `new`.

Luckily in modern c++ you (generally) don't need to use raw pointers and not need to worry about this. `std::shared_ptr<T>` created by `std::make_shared<T,Args...>`, and `std::unique_ptr<T>` created by `std::make_unique<T,Args...>`. These are wrappers for pointers. `std::shared_ptr<T>` is just `T*`, but when everybody loses the pointer to the object, the memory is returned. `std::unique_ptr<T>` is the same, but only one reference exists.

A `std::unique_ptr<T>` LinkedList from cppreference:

```cpp
#include <memory>
struct List {
  struct Node {
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    Node(int data) : data{data}, next{nullptr} {}
  };
  List() : head{nullptr} {};
  // N.B. iterative destructor to avoid stack overflow on long lists
  ~List() { while(head) head = std::move(head->next); }
  // copy/move and other APIs skipped for simplicity
  void push(int data) {
    auto temp = std::make_unique<Node>(data);
    if(head) temp->next = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(temp);
  }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
};
```

As to an other reason the use of `new` should be minimised: Apart from the above issue of potential memory leak, is that it is very expensive (`std::make_shared`/`std::make_unique` still has this issue though), as the program needs to ask the kernel to grant it some memory, meaning an expensive system call must be made.